# Difference between Log Analytics Solutions, Insights and Workbooks

Tags: azure, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am looking for a clear explanation for what is the difference between "Solutions" in log analytics workspace (recently marked "legacy") vs Application Insights/Container Insights/X Insights vs Workbooks that appear in both Log Analytics Workspaces and Application Insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Solutions in Log Analytics Workspace:** "Solutions" in Log Analytics Workspace refers to pre-packaged solutions or management packs that can be deployed to collect, analyze, and act on data from various sources. These solutions are designed to address specific scenarios or workloads, such as security, compliance, or performance monitoring. For reference check this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/azure-monitor/insights/solutions?tabs=portal).
- **Application Insights:** It is a service in Azure that is designed for monitoring and gaining insights into the performance and usage of applications. It helps to track requests, exceptions, dependencies, and other telemetry data from applications. For reference check this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview).
- **Container Insights:** It is part of Azure Monitor, focuses on monitoring and gaining insights into the performance of containers and orchestrators like Kubernetes. It provides information about container health, performance, and logs. For reference check this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-overview).
- **X Insights:** The "X Insights" placeholder represents various specific services or features tailored for specific scenarios. For example, if there were a service named "Database Insights," it will focus on monitoring and gaining insights into database performance. For reference check this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/insights-overview).
- **Workbooks:** Workbooks are interactive, customizable reports in Azure Monitor that you can use to analyze and visualize data from your Log Analytics Workspace. It allows to create dashboards and reports to gain insights into your data. For reference check this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview).

  Application Insights also supports Workbooks, allowing to create custom reports and dashboards specifically tailored to application monitoring and diagnostics.

In summary, "Solutions" in Log Analytics Workspace (Legacy) are pre-packaged configurations for specific scenarios, while Application Insights, Container Insights, and other "X Insights" services focus on monitoring and gaining insights into specific types of resources. Workbooks are a cross-cutting feature that allows you to create custom reports and dashboards in both Log Analytics Workspaces and Application Insights.

**`Example`:**

***Solution (log Analytics workspace) :***
I have solutions in my workspace which is `Performing Assessment` and `SQL Vulnerability`. `SQL Vulnerability` will show any SQL vulnerability available in the source. you can add or deploy additional solutions from marketplace by clicking on `+Add`.

[image]

[image]

***Application Insights :***
It will show all data of Application which it is associated with. I have created a node.js function. and the application insight is showing all types of data related to that function.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does it mean that solutions are "legacy"? Are they being replaced with workbooks?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda Solution are "legacy" means those are not active in deployment as mentioned in `caution` section in the document of `solutions` and its replacement are Insights, you can check in this [document's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/insights-overview) `note` section.

Comment: I hope this answers your question :) @Piotr Gwiazda